# Accepting Data From a Form And Saving It To MongoDB through Mongoose & Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Should be simple but I’ve hit a snag.

The form is as simple as possible. Just a title field and a body field.

I expected to get an object back from the form that looked something like this:

```
{title:'The Title', body:'This is some body text'}
```

Or maybe this:

```
{'title':'The Title', 'body':'This is some body text'}
```

Instead what I got back is this:

```
{ '”title”': 'The Title', '”body”': 'This is some body text' }
```

The object keys, title & body, are enclosed in **both single and double quotes**.

The object that was saved to the database looked like this:

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("6182e9ed83c9bbfd6e753ac5"), __v: 0 }
```

In other words, the document that was saved to the database had an ObjectId and nothing else. I checked this by examining the database with Compass.

I then hardcoded the object I wanted, overwriting what I had received from the form. That resulted in this being saved on the database:

```
{
  title: 'The Title',
  body: 'This is some body text',
  _id: new ObjectId("6182ea6b2b5a9c8ea3324668"),
  __v: 0
}
```

So the problem clearly is enclosing object keys in both single and double quotes. I spent a whole afternoon researching this but I’m stuck.

I then encountered another problem. No matter how hard I tried I was unable to post the question because I kept getting a message along the following lines:

You appear to have incorrectly formatted code

After three hours I gave up. You can find my code in a PDF. Here is the link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ShfIKNXwEHBuxJ_uBGEf9s1jxb-DripB/view

It's very straightforward textbook stuff. You got straight to the bottom and see the express post coding.

HELP!!!!!

**CLIENT SIDE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <%-include('layouts/header');-%>

    <body>

        <!-- Navigation-->

        <%-include('layouts/navbar');-%>

        <!-- Page Header-->

        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/img/contact-bg.jpg')">

            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">

                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">

                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">

                        <div class="page-heading">

                            <h1>Create New Post</h1>

                            <span class="subheading">Have questions? I have answers.</span>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </header>

        <!-- Main Content-->

        <div> 

     
            <form action="/posts/store" method="POST">

                <label>Title</label><br>
 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="title" name=”title”>

                <br>

                <label>Body</label><br>

                <textarea rows="5" id="body" name=”body” ></textarea>

            <br>

                <button type="submit" >Send</button>

            
            </form> 

        </div>

            
            <!-- (all formatting removed from form)--->

        <!-- Footer-->

        <%-include('layouts/footer');-%>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->

        <%-include('layouts/scripts');-%>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Core theme JS-->

        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

        <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *-->

        <!-- * *                               SB Forms JS                               * *-->

        <!-- * * Activate your form at https://startbootstrap.com/solution/contact-forms * *-->

        <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *-->

        <script src="https://cdn.startbootstrap.com/sb-forms-latest.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add some markup to your question. Read [how do I format my posts using MarkDown or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more details. It will help make your question and code more readable.

Comment: Also, include the related code to your question **as code** in your question. Sharing a link to a PDF of your code is creating more steps for the people trying to help, let alone it can create potential security risk for other users. SO has adequate formatting and a snippet editor in which you can present and even run your code.

Comment: Hi. Believe me I tried for three hours to do what you suggested. I was still unable to post. No matter what I tried I kept getting this message saying my code was improperly formatted. Apologies for any inconveience.

Comment: Please provide your client side code

Comment: Hi Mohammad, added client side code above. I should add that I've removed all the bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line
`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="title" name=”title”>`
change `name=”title”` to `name="title"`

and do it for this line `<textarea rows="5" id="body" name=”body” ></textarea>`
change `name=”body”` to `name="body"`

Comment: Thank you. Now I feel really stupid. I've been looking at that code for hours and I did not realise I had the wrong quotes.